# Positioning of labels according to the length of the text

Tags: swift

I have a requirement of displaying labels in a table view.The number of labels in tableview cell and the length of those are generating dynamically.

For example if user selects 10 names in a popup, those names should be displayed in 10 different labels in tableviewcell and the length of text may vary...How to achieve this....Thanks in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztme6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
theLabelToUse.sizeToFit()
```

First concatenate the strings of different names into a single string that you want to display in the label. This will update the label frame to fit the content.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...This works good to fit the text inside label but when the length of the text is more the text size is reducing i want label to be expanded when the text length is more.

Answer (score 0):

You will definitely meet scenarios when the labels cannot all fit on the screen, so you will need the `UITableViewCell` to be horizontally scrollable.

The easiest solution for this would be to embed a `UICollectionView` inside you table view cells. Your collection view cells only need to have a single label. Set the `scrollDirection` to horizontal and set up your `dataSource` methods such that the collection view only has 1 row.

Comment: Yea...I have tried this approach.But the problem is the labels in the second row are visible only if i scroll..I need to display all labels together, that means table view cell should resize as collectionview expands.I have tried with tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60 and autolayout...but the tableview is not resizing.

Comment: If you do what I describe in my answer, you will only have 1 row in your collection view, which is horizontally scrollable and hence the table view cells' height doesn't need to be dynamic.

Comment: UI specification given is tableviewcell should expand as number of cells increases...not scrolling

Comment: I have inserted the image in the question